# Laurent series for $0 < |z-i| < \infty$ for $\frac{1}{(z-i)^2}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I would like help with a question that has me a little puzzled. Here it is, transcribed:

"Find the Laurent series expansion for each of the following functions in the given region:

(...)

$$ f(z) = \frac{1}{(z-i)^2}\quad  , \quad 0 \lt |z-i| \lt \infty $$

I would have thought this was already the expansion about $z_0 = i$, with $a_{-2} = 1$ and with every other term $a_k = 0$.

How do I get started with finding the series?

Thank you

Comment: If you're expanding about $z_0=i$, then you're correct.

Comment: Thank you very much. There must have been a misunderstanding when I asked my professor about it.